# Can a JSON body passthrough as JSON object instead of string in the AWS Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to setup a Lambda Integration on AWS Gateway to just passthrough a JSON body as object without converting it to string(the canonical example `"body": "$input.json('$')"`). I've tried different functions from `$input` and `$utils`, as well as their combinations. So far, the closest I got from the behavior I'm expecting was using the following mapping template:

```
{
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "body": $input.body
}
```

It works fine when I test from the AWS web UI but fails once the API is deployed and tested from outside. It fails because `$input.body` is passed as a base64 instead of JSON object.

Is there a work around to bypass the body as a JSON object to the AWS lambda using the template above? And why testing from the AWS web UI behaves different from the actual deployed endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

As expected, it was a bad configuration on my side. It turns out that `application/json` was set up as a binary media type (under `Settings -> Binary Media Types`) and this was automatically encoding the body content in Base64.

Moreover the mapping template can also use `$input.json('$')` instead. This will add basic validation to the json body and it'll avoid bad formed json to reach your lambda function.